# Oddity with ToExpression

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

Is this a bug?

```
ToExpression["3231.432"]
```

> 3231.43

I would have expected the following:

> 3231.432

I am using Mathematica 10.2.0

Comment: What do you see when you simply type `3231.43` and hit enter?  It's just the number of displayed digits, the 2 is still there.

Comment: Jason B, It still seems to be a bug.

Comment: Edit -> Preferences -> Appearance -> Numbers -> Formatting -> "Numbers of digits displayed in output"

Answer (score 4):

I think this is only a display issue:

If you set

```
x=3231.432
```

you also get

```
3231.42
```

as a return. However, if you evaluate, say,

```
x-3000
```

the missing digit (2) will appear again. I guess Mathematica only displays five significant figures (per default). Hope this helps.